# Styles in XAML doesn't work

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, styles, tabitem

Why the color of the `TabItems` is always black? I want black `Background` and white letters. Also the `Button` should be white, but it's black too and not visible. There is some conflict but can't find where. Any ideas? Thx in advance for your help.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.Test"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
         xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"   
         xmlns:cm="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro"
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="252" d:DesignWidth="894" Background="#FF111111">    

<Grid>        
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" FontSize="48" Margin="70,-14.668,0,0" FontWeight="Light"><Run Language="de-at" Text="test test"/></TextBlock>
    <Button x:Name="Close" Content="➔" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="58" Foreground="White" Height="58" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" FontSize="40" Margin="-7.625,-8,0,0" Padding="1,-5,1,1" Clip="M50.333,8 L-1.667,8 L-1.667,59.843 L50.333,59.843 z" cm:Message.Attach="Close()">
        <Button.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1" ScaleX="-1"/>
                <SkewTransform AngleY="0" AngleX="0"/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Button.RenderTransform>
    </Button>

    <TabControl Margin="42,52,0,0">
        <TabItem Header="Start">

        </TabItem>
            <TabItem Foreground="White" Header="Start 1" >

        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Foreground="White" Header="Start 1">

        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Foreground="White" Header="Start 1">

        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Foreground="White" Header="Start 1">

        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>       
</Grid>
```

I tried many things and it didn't work. So what i did is put a `TextBlock` inside the `TabItem.Header`:

```
<TabItem>
    <TabItem.Header>
        <TextBlock FontSize="25" Text="Start1" />
    </TabItem.Header>
</TabItem>
```

Now I can change the color of the `TextBlock` with `Foreground`. But don't know how to change the `TextBlock` color if I click on the `TabItem`. Maybe I should open a new topic for that. Thanks all for your contribution.

Comment: How do you expect us to give you an answer. We don't know what is in all the resource dictionaries.

Comment: i deleted the dictionaries and still no change

Comment: Can your share your latest xaml code?

Comment: i just edited the code Anand

Comment: Where is the "MetroCircleButtonStyle"? I just tried this code, and tab items looks normal (foreground is white).

Comment: i deleted it also..but i get only black background..TabItems are not visibile

Comment: Could you please share us updated version of this code.. In addition, you want black background, but i couldn't see the black background setting.

Comment: I edited the code couple of minutes ago..the Black Background is         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="252" d:DesignWidth="894" Background="#FF111111" >

Comment: OK. Could you please share us screenshot of your black view..

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting the `Background` or `Foreground` properties of your `TabControl` at all, so it's using the default colors.

The default color of the `Background` property of any `Control` object is `Brushes.Transparent` ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.background.aspx)), while the default `Foreground` property is based on your system colors ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.foreground.aspx)).

You can use an implicit style in your `UserControl.Resources` to set a property for all objects of the specified type, such as using this style for all Control objects:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Or if you can add a new Brush to your `.Resources` and set it's `x:Key` to the System Key of one of the [SystemColors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2010/11/30/systemcolors-reference.aspx) , like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowColorKey}" Color="Black"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrush}" Color="White"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

(You might need to test a bit to figure out which is the correct SystemColors Key to use. You can find a list of them [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2010/11/30/systemcolors-reference.aspx))

Comment: i put your code inside my xaml(right before <Grid>) but still doesn't work..i am going to create new project later and try again..thx

Comment: @Georg See my updated answer. I probably had the SystemColors key incorrect.